# How can I disable keys on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to disable keys on the iPhone virtual keyboard, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

The game has to disable keys. How can I do the same from my own application?

Comment: Good question, I'd like to know too. Love the screenshot though.